# Formatting data to .csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following string

```
string = "First Name | Last Name | Age"
```

when I print it looks like this:

```
First Name | Last Name | Age
```

When I print to csv file

```
writer.writerow(datac[0])
```

looks like this:

```
F, i, r, s, t and so on...
```

How do I get to to print in single row? like this

```
Row1 

First Name | Last Name | Age
```

Comment: Have you tried `writer.writerow([datac[0]])`?

Comment: Are `First Name`, `Last Name`, and `Age` supposed to be separate columns?

Answer (score 2):

`writer.writerow()` is expecting a sequence.  Since strings are sequences of characters, it's being interpreted that way.

If your row contains only a single element, you could indicate that like this: `writer.writerow([datac[0]])` or `writer.writerow(datac[0:1])`

Comment: This is correct, but possibly missing something.  The very last line of his question shows that he may be expecting to write three (pipe delimeted?) columns, not one.  (Incidentally, a csv file with one column doesn't need a separator.)  If `datac` contains three items, what he really needs would be `writer.writerow(datac)`.

Comment: If pipe-delimited is desired, pass the delimiter to the csv writer constructor:  `writer = csv.writer(a_file, delimiter='|')`

Answer (score 1):

writer.writerow() expects a sequence and when you give it a string it treats it as a sequence of charecters. 
Try doing this.

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
string = "First Name | Last Name | Age"
writer.writerow(string.split('|'))
```

Comment: Unless you set your csv separator as `'|'`, this will output using commas as delimiters, which seems to be different from what is desired.